# how to get text from hidden html row using selenium webdriver java

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Here is the html row element:

```
<tr style="display:none">
           <td>23</td>
          <td class="mandatory">
           Overall Percentage
           </td>
           <td>
           50
           </td>
</tr>
```

---

```
String overallProgress = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"DivBuilding\"]/div/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[23]/td[3]")).getText();
```

This does not work. I understand findElement gets only visible data, how can I resolve this?

My HTML is like below:

```
<tr style="display:none"> <td>11</td> <td class="mandatory"> Overall Percentage of Completion of the work done For the entire Building /Wing </td> <td> 31.5 </td> </tr>
```

I would like to get the number "31.5" from the above

Comment: <tr style="display:none">
                                        <td>11</td>
                                        <td class="mandatory">
                                            Overall Percentage of Completion of the
                                            work done  For the entire Building /Wing
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            31.5
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>

Comment: I would like to get the number "31.5" from the above

Comment: can you share little more HTML

Comment: @nishesh, thanks for that pointer, after going through it  again, I got it working.